# RSS feed keeps kicking me

Tags: discussion

I signed up fo the RSS feed for Harry Potter question back in 2011 and have had no problem until recently. Suddenly, I'm not getting *any* Harry Potter questions via RSS. I've signed up several times since this started and I'll get, oh, five to ten questions via RSS and then the feed disappears again. I'm missing a lot of questions because of this -- does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can permanently fix it?

Comment: They may be rate-limited. How often is your software polling?

Comment: Wow, I have no idea -- would you happen to know how to find out this information? I wonder why it would be fine for over two years, but then give me a problem.

Comment: Repairo RSSo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out why I wasn't getting all the HP questions:

[image: SciFi.SE RSS Feed]

The questions are sent out in batches, I guess. I will miss them coming through one at a time.